# ffmpeg as mp3DirectCut alternative for .m4a

Tags: ffmpeg, m4a

I'm trying to use ffmpeg for trimming .m4a files, i.e. discarding some parts at the beginning and at the end and applying fade-in and fade-out effects around the remaining part, which I'd like to preserve as is - without re-compressing.
Basically something mp3DirectCut can do for mp3 files.

So far results are not great. Is that doable?

Some more details about what I'm doing:
desired result
[image]

Splitting files with ffmpeg works ok. I can concatenate the files back and the resulting file plays just like the original one. I even tried to split source to thousands tiny files and then build the original file - still everything ok.

```
ffmpeg -i source.m4a -vn -c copy -f segment -segment_times 7.500574201520601,9.850499533190922,1559.5357313024108,1564.7855644901852 -segment_start_number 1 temp%d.m4a
```

Next step is to apply fade-in and fade-out filters on fragments 2 and 4.

```
ffmpeg -i temp2.m4a -af afade=t=in:curve=desi:st=0:d=1.8799402653362565 -c:a libfdk_aac -profile:a aac_he -b:a 95k tempFadeIn.m4a

ffmpeg  -i temp4.m4a -af afade=t=out:curve=desi:st=0.5249833187774356:d=4.199866550219485 -c:a libfdk_aac -profile:a aac_he -b:a 95k tempFadeOut.m4a
```

Last step is to concatenate 3 parts back together:

```
ffmpeg -f concat  -safe 0 -i concat.txt  -c copy final.m4a
```

This last operation gives two warnings of the following type:

> Non-monotonous DTS in output stream 0:0; previous: 74501074, current:
> 74498064; changing to 74501075. This may result in incorrect
> timestamps in the output file.

In the resulting file sound is distorted at the stitches and waveform shows there small gaps.
Depending on the player used distortions sound differently - so it looks like corrupted file rather than the actual silence inserted:

- ffplay - silence
- vlc - silence sometimes followed by loud noise in one channel
- wavesurfer.js (which I'm using as GUI) - loud "vinyl crack"

Answer (score 0):

If I am not wrong your timescale is different in both the streams that you are trying to concatenate try matching the timescales of both streams before concatenating.

I fixed the same issue with this flag `-video_track_timescale 90000` but my streams had both audio and video. I haven't tried this for just audio I also could not find a flag for audio timescale in the FFMPEG docs. So I would suggest you should try to use the above mentioned flag. If it still does not work you can try setting the **timebase** and the **audio sampling frequency (eg. -ar 48000)** if you still need a better explanation please refer to this:  https://video.stackexchange.com/a/34392